# how do i get mysql to work with python 3.6 in anaconda ide (spyder)?

Tags: python, mysql, anaconda

I am using a windows 10  64bit OS.

I downloaded the file (mysqlclient-1.3.10-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (md5)) from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient, as suggested by another post.

But i am not able to import this whl file into the packages using the conda install command..

Any suggestion will be appreciated..

Also, I am just beginning with python coding, so please keep the answers newbie-friendly :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just realized that one can use pip install to install the whl file...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with the same setup and problem,

[anaconda / packages / mysql-connector-python](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/mysql-connector-python)

```
conda install -c anaconda mysql-connector-python=2.0.4
```

Comment: I have Python 3.6.1 | Anaconda 4.4.0 and it worked without the python version - i.e. $ conda install -c anaconda mysql-connector-python